# Thymeleaf fragment logic

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

So I try to create a simple page layout for my spring app, just a header and a content. 
Generally it is not really complicated, I can create a header fragment, insert in in any of the views and it works just fine.

Now I would like to add avatar and user name in the header. The first thing I can think of is creating a code which will handle this header logic, somehow fetching the user and putting it in the model so that it can be properly processed by thymeleaf.

Any way to do it? I mean is there a way to include a fragment in views but not calling any functions manually in the respective controllers (to fetch user, or generally to do the logic of a fragment)?

edit: basically I would like to do equivalent of angular directive.

Comment: spring-security and thymeleaf works well together. [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-security-thymeleaf-example/)

Comment: Well the one with user is just an example. I might want to do another fragment lets say for displaying ads. I'd like to provide a logic for this (for example to fetch appropriate ads with java code rather than async loading it with javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bean References](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-bean-references) to call methods directly on beans.

For example, below I have defined a `UserService` bean which has a `getCurrentUser` method. Within a Thymeleaf expression you can use `@userService.getCurrentUser()` to call that method.

UserService:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    public User getCurrentUser() {
        User user = ... do some work to get current user
        return user;
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<div>
    Logged in as: <span th:text="${@userService.getCurrentUser().getName()}"></span>
</div>
```